# Server-level OData feed in AzDevOps Server?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-reports, azure-devops-analytics

I recall reading that AzDevOps had an OData feed on collection, project, **and server** level. When I hit  the latter on my AzDevOps 2019.1 box at `http://tfs.example.com:8080/tfs/_odata/v1.0/`, I get the following error:

```
{
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "VS403514: The Analytics feature is not enabled. Details on enabling this feature are available here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2093060.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Analytics.AnalyticsNotEnabledException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Analytics.Server",
  "typeKey": "AnalyticsNotEnabledException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3000
}
```

Analytics is enabled for every collection on the server. All collection level OData feeds work. If there's a server-level "Enable Analytics" setting, I couldn't find it - neither in the Web UI, nor in the admin console. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, where do you see the Server level info? It seems that only project-level and org-level [are documented.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/account-scoped-queries?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I recall I was going by this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/account-scoped-queries?view=azure-devops Now that I look at it again, I think "organization" in VSTS is equivalent to a team collection in TFS. Guess there's no cross-collection analytics anymore, now that the OLAP cube is pretty much gone. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but as I know there's no server-level Analytics.

Azure Devops Service and Azure Devops Server use [organization (In Azure Devops Server it's called team collection) and project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#how-do-you-manage-work-across-the-enterprise) to manage the work. The server you mentions above represents all the organizations in one Azure Devops Server while all the [Rest APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [Odata tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/quick-ref?view=azure-devops) are for Org-level or Project-level.

Comment: You mean no **more** server level analytics :) The `Tfs_Analysis` OLAP database did a fine job, until Microsoft decided it had to go away.

Comment: If you do need the server-level odata feed, try posting a feature request here in [user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html). The team would consider your needs seriously if it gets enough points :)

Comment: Filed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1027767/server-level-odata-feed.html